# reading Planner Tasks returns 403 and 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am getting a token using grant type authorization_code with scope Tasks.Read. I then use it in request

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks/
```

For my personal account it returns 404 Not Found.
For my work account it returns 403 Forbidden.
How do I make it work?
I want to read the tasks and its attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `404` is expected since Planner Tasks are not supported by personal Microsoft accounts.

For AAD accounts, you require either the `Group.Read.All` or `Group.ReadWrite.All` [permission scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint). Both of these permissions require [Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) from a Tenant Administrator before you can use them.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint):

> **Delegated permissions** are used by apps that have a signed-in user present. For these apps either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests and the app can act as the signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph. Some delegated permissions can be consented by non-administrative users, but some higher-privileged permissions require [administrator consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint).